# Android webview crashe - base.apk!libmonochrome.so

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

We seem to be getting crashes in Google play console related to web views on Android 10 and 11. Not specific to any device or manufacturer as we have seen this across a wide variety of devices. There is not much information other than cryptic stack traces. I have shown below some of the stack traces we have seen. We use webview in our app.

```
1. backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000001f12f48  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-DL6ix9Uo56258eyHybnAww==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (offset 0x2e0000)

2. backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000019a92a0  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_447207730-4UicC18QRnCjyz0DmzBsEg==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (offset 0x645000)

3. backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000017e55a2  /data/app/com.android.chrome-Mgz9EBxcd2AEMaApPwp9Jw==/base.apk (offset 0xb3e000)
```

As, we were not able to reproduce it in our environment here and not much information available in the stack trace, we did some search on the internet and some people were saying this could be related to the Android System Webview and Chrome issue that had a widespread impact in March 2021. However, in our case these seem to be up to date.

Any thoughts or pointers on what could be causing this issue or how we can debug this further would be of great help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a way to get detsils about the user so that we can notify them about the resolve - https://support.google.com/android/thread/103561027?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can only wait for them to update there libraries, mostly google ads libraries, As ads are shown in a web view related chrome based UI, the only thing we can do is they update it and resolve, from your point I think there is nothing you can do about it

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. We don't have ads in our app. However, we use webview to show web content related to our app.